# MudTable make table rows draggable

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, blazor, mudblazor

I want to create draggable table rows with MudTable. To be able to set the draggable attribute on a tr element, I used the ChildRowContent and left the RowTemplate empty, since RowTemplate will generate the tr element automatically having no ability to set attributes like draggable.

```
<ChildRowContent>
    <MudTr draggable="true"
                ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
                ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('', event.target.id);"
                @ondrop="HandleDrop"
                @ondragenter="HandleDragEnter"
                @ondragleave="HandleDragLeave">
        <MudTd>Col</MudTd>
    </MudTr>
</ChildRowContent>
```

But unfortunately when I drag a table row It seems to drag the whole table. Is there an easier way to achieve this with MudTable?

Comment: This seems to be caused by the mat-ripple class on a MudButton which is used inside a table column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by a MudMenu element inside a column, which was rendering a  with a "map-ripple" class.
By setting `<MudMenu DisableRipple="true">` this issue can be resolved. Now when I drag a row it will only drag the row and not other parts of the UI.

Edit: Here is the full example code:

```
<div>
<MudTable T="GridModel"
    Items="@Items"
    Dense
    Hover>
    <ColGroup>
        <col class="action-column" />
        <col class="action-column" />
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>
        </MudTh>
        <MudTh>
            #
        </MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>

    </RowTemplate>
    <ChildRowContent>
        <MudTr ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
            @ondragenter="() => DragEnter(context.Index, false)"
            @ondrop="async () => await DropAsync(context.Index)"
            Class="@($"{(IsEntering(context.Index) && draggedItem?.Index != context.Index - 1 ? "enter" : "hide")} {(enterAfterDropZone == false ? "dropzone" : "")}")">
                <MudTd colspan="2">
                </MudTd>
        </MudTr>
        <MudTr
            draggable="@IsDraggable()"
            @ondragstart="() => DragStart(context)"
            @ondragenter="() => DragEnter(context.Index, false)"
            @ondrop="() => DropAsync(context.Index)"
            @ondragend="() => DragEnd()"
            Class="grabable">  
            <MudTd>
                <MudMenu Icon="@Icons.Filled.MoreVert" Size="Size.Small" DisableRipple="true">
                   
                </MudMenu>
            </MudTd>
            <MudTd>
                @(context.Index + 1)
            </MudTd>
        </MudTr>
        <MudTr ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
            @ondragenter="() => DragEnter(context.Index, true)"
                   @ondrop="() => DropAsync(draggedItem?.Index < context.Index ? context.Index : context.Index + 1)"
                   Class="@($"{(IsEntering(context.Index) && draggedItem?.Index != context.Index + 1 ? "enter" : "hide")} {(enterAfterDropZone == true ? "dropzone" : "")}")">
                <MudTd colspan="2">
                </MudTd>
        </MudTr>
    </ChildRowContent>
</MudTable>
</div>


public partial class Component
{
    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public IEnumerable<GridModel> Items { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;

    private GridModel? draggedItem;

    private int? enterIndex;
    private bool? enterAfterDropZone;

    private void DragStart(GridModel model)
    {
        draggedItem = model;
    }

    private void DragEnter(int index, bool isAfterDropZone)
    {
        if(draggedItem?.Index == index)
        {
            enterIndex = null;
            enterAfterDropZone = null;
        }
        else
        {
            enterIndex = index;
            enterAfterDropZone = isAfterDropZone;
        }
    }

    private async Task DropAsync(int index)
    {
        DragEnd();
    }
    
    private void DragEnd()
    {
        draggedItem = null;
        enterIndex = null;
        enterAfterDropZone = null;
    }
    
    private bool IsEntering(int index)
    {
        return enterIndex == index;
    }

    private string IsDraggable()
    {
        return "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your whole table with dragable rows?

Comment: @Patrick I added it in the answer.